# How can I have my ant task pass or fail based on the results of a jar it runs?

Tags: java, ant

I'm running CrossCheck (browserless js unit testing) as part of an ant script. I'd like ant to report failure if the CrossCheck tests fail. Here's the relevant bit from the build.xml

```
<target name="test" depends="concat">
    <java jar="src/test/lib/crosscheck.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="src/test/webapp/js/"/>
    </java>
```

And an example of CrossCheck's failure messaging:

```
 [java] Running tests in environment: Mozilla 1.7 (Firefox 1.0)
 [java] org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "clusterNode" is not defined. (ResultXMLWrapperTest.js#22)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3229)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3219)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(ScriptRuntime.java:3292)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.nameOrFunction(ScriptRuntime.java:1636)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(ScriptRuntime.java:1575)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c1(ResultXMLWrapperTest.js:22)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(ResultXMLWrapperTest.js)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:340)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2758)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(ResultXMLWrapperTest.js)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.AbstractScopeFactory$1.run(AbstractScopeFactory.java:108)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:515)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:450)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.AbstractScopeFactory.initTestScope(AbstractScopeFactory.java:94)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.DefaultScopeFactory.getTestScope(DefaultScopeFactory.java:68)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.TestCase$1.run(TestCase.java:119)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:528)
 [java]     at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:450)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:117)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:95)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.Crosscheck.runAll(Crosscheck.java:116)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.ConsoleRunner.run(ConsoleRunner.java:140)
 [java]     at net.thefrontside.crosscheck.framework.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:300)
 [java] ReferenceError: "clusterNode" is not defined. (ResultXMLWrapperTest.js#22)
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Can ant get at the results of the CrossCheck test (perhaps Java Result: 1 gets passed back to ant?) and succeed or fail based on that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that CrossCheck returns a non-zero return code on a error you could add the `failonerror` attribute to the java task:

```
<target name="test" depends="concat">
    <java jar="src/test/lib/crosscheck.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="src/test/webapp/js/"/>
    </java>
```

See the documentation on the Ant [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'failonerror' attribute of the 'java' task.

> failonerror   Stop the buildprocess if
>   the command exits with a returncode
>   other than 0. Default is "false" (see
>   note)

Check the Ant manual [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).